# bitwise AND doesn't work on MSB

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, bit-manipulation

I'm implementing a bit vector by packing bits into an array of uints. The `getBit(index)` function does a `(array[cell] & (1 << bit)) >> bit` to get whether a bit has been set or not. This works perfectly well for all bits except the MSB. An example of where it doesn't work is as follows.

```
array[cell] = 11111001 11100000 00000000 00000000
(1 << bit)  = 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
& operation = 01111001 11100000 00000000 00000000
```

I can't figure out why the Bitwise AND operation seems to be operating like an XOR. Either that or the MSB got unset. Can anyone explain whats happening?

Edit: Actual code

```
var cell:uint = int(index / 32);
var bit:uint = 32 - (index % 32) - 1;
return (array[cell] & (1 << bit)) >> bit;
```

In the instance that doesn't work, `index = 0`

Comment: Can you paste the actual code you wrote please?

Comment: Performance hint, now that the signed/unsigned issue is resolved: rather than shifting back the bit to the LSB position, you could test whether the result of the AND is zero nor not.

Comment: Better, yet, see Daniel Fisher's elegant and efficient solution, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unsigned shift.

```
(uint(array[cell]) & (uint(1) << bit)) >>> bit
```

Comment: The shift doesn't seem to be the problem, the `&` operation itself gives the wrong result

Comment: OK, convert `array[cell]` to uint prior to bitwise-and.

Comment: :( That didn't help either

Comment: It needed one more `uint` as in `uint(uint(1) << bit)`. Worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If all values are such that things are well-defined,

```
(array[cell] & (1 << bit)) >> bit
```

is equivalent to the simpler

```
(array[cell] >> bit) & 1
```

for unsigned integers.

I'm not familiar with Action Script, but it could be that `1 << 31` behaves oddly because `1` is a signed integer.

Aside remark,

```
var bit:uint = 32 - (index % 32) - 1;
```

looks odd, usually one would use `index % 32` as the bit number.

Comment: about the bit number, I'm storing it MSB to LSB. I guess `index%32` would store it LSB to MSB. Also, the simpler equation solves my problem because I no longer have to deal with MSB. Thanks!

Comment: Aks: give it a +1 at least, this elegant solution needs to perk to to the top!